# Envio de Imagem multipart com MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: java

boa tarde.
A imagem não está sendo enviada para o end-point de envio post de imagem. Ja revisei todo o codigo, más infelizmente não to encontrando o problema. O retorno do servidor é 200. Más a imagem não ta indo.

Agradeço muito a ajuda!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
public class mainUpload {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost uploadFile = null;
    uploadFile = new HttpPost("http://URLINTERNO");
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

    // This attaches the file to the POST:
    File f = new File("/Users/PC/Desktop/img/imagem.png");
    try {
        builder.addBinaryBody("file", new FileInputStream(f), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, f.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
    uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("ta aqui:" + responseEntity.toString());
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println(response.getEntity());
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

alterei algumas coisas. mesmo assim nada. por favor, me ajuda.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
```

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class mainUpload3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
File f = new File("/Users/PC/Desktop/img/sankhya.png");

```
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                             .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                             .addPart("arquivo", fileBody);
    HttpEntity multiPartEntity = builder.build();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://192.168.4.16:8280/mge/sessionUpload.mge?sessionkey=Produto_IMAGEM9&fitem=S&salvar=S&useCache=N");

    httpPost.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
    // betterPrint(httpPost);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println(result.getContentType());
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(response);

}
```

}

Comment: Se mudou o código pode editar a pergunta original. Este campo é exclusivo para respostas.